# multidimensinal array: group and output php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Hi I have this array coming in:

```
$myRegionData =
    array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [howmuch] => 1 
            [country] => ID 
            [state] => JAWA BARAT 

           ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [howmuch] => 1 
            [country] => RO 
            [state] => BUCURESTI 
         ) 

    [2] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [howmuch] => 2 
            [country] => US 
            [state] => CALIFORNIA 
         ) 

    [3] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [howmuch] => 1 
            [country] => US 
            [state] => TEXAS  
          )
      )
```

Im trying to group the array outuput as such

```
ID
 JAWA BARAT (1) 
RO
 BUCURESTI (1)
US
 CALIFORNIA (2)
 TEXAS (1)
```

I have tried Key value associations, i Loops etc.. and I  can seem to combine the US states in the display.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd reorganise it by country first to make things easier:

```
// will hold the re-indexed array
$indexed = array();

// store each state's object under the country identifier
foreach($myRegionData as $object) {
    if(!isset($indexed[$object->country])) {
        $indexed[$object->country] = array();
    }

    $indexed[$object->country][] = $object;
}

// output the data
foreach($indexed as $country => $states) {
    echo $country, "\n";
    foreach($states as $state) {
        printf(" %s (%u)\n", $state->state, $state->howmuch);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well. Can you help me understand this: $indexed[$object->country][] = $object;

Comment: `$indexed[$object->country]` is an array, and `[]` appends an element to the end of it. It's equivalent to [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).